# Get mail from folder within Inbox - EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I want to access emails in a folder called "ITServiceDesk" in my exchange inbox.

I can access the folder but i cant figure out how to read the mail inside that folder.

I am accessing the folder here:

```
            var view = new FolderView(100);
            view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
            var fileview = new ItemView(100);
            var filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "ITServiceDesk");

            // Read 100 mails
            foreach (var item in _service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, filter, view))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.DisplayName);
                foreach (EmailMessage email in _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, filter, fileview))
                {
                    email.Load(new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.ConversationTopic, ItemSchema.Attachments,
                        ItemSchema.TextBody));
                    MessageBox.Show(email.ConversationTopic);
                    MessageBox.Show(email.TextBody);
                }
            }
```

Nothing happens when i get inside the second foreach loop. The message box shows that it can find the folder as the item.displayname is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are finding the folder with you code then just call the findItem method on the Folder object that is returned eg

```
                foreach (var Folder in _service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, filter, view))
            {                   
                MessageBox.Show(Folder.DisplayName);

                foreach (EmailMessage email in Folder.FindItems(fileview))
                {
                    email.Load(new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.ConversationTopic, ItemSchema.Attachments,
                        ItemSchema.TextBody));
                    MessageBox.Show(email.ConversationTopic);
                    MessageBox.Show(email.TextBody);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Perfect! Does exactly what i wanted, dont know why i couldnt figure that out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from my website:

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults 
                    = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView( 10 ) );

foreach ( Item item in findResults.Items )
   Console.WriteLine( item.Subject );
```

See [C#: Getting All Emails From Exchange using Exchange Web Services](http://omegacoder.com/?p=454)

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but this only finds items in the Inbox, not from a specific folder within the inbox?

Comment: See [Work with folders by using EWS in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-work-with-folders-by-using-ews-in-exchange#get-a-folder-by-using-ews)